# Button on form submits to search and not the form itself

Tags: html, button, post

I am running into an issue where submitting my form tries to POST to my search.php instead of requests.php like it should.

Search button on sidebar:

```
                <li class="sidebar-search">
                <form class="search" action="search.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="results" placeholder="Search...">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="search">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /input-group -->
                </li>
```

Submit button for form:

```
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                              <form class="request" action="requests.php" method="POST">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <form role="form">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Address</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Enter address">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Info</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" name="info" placeholder="Enter info such as S/B, Locates, promised, fence/grass">
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" name="request" class="btn btn-default">Submit Button</button>
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Button</button>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that you've forgotten to close the form tag

somewhere around this html comment "<!-- /input-group -->"
you should add

```
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2v049ksy/

Comment: Wow, so simple. Thanks

Comment: i've got stuck by these kind of things countless times. But ever since i've installed [sublimelinter-html-tidy](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-html-tidy) (html checking plugin for sublime text) I have a lot less of these errors. Really great tool to find small errors like this. It's uses [html tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/). You could look into that to see if it works for your workflow.